# Base64.js add date/time or strings to the decoded text while keyup()

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
//html

       <label for="encode" class="encode"></label>
       <label for="decode" class="decode"></label>
       <textarea id="encode"></textarea>
       <textarea id="decode"></textarea>

// default base64.js code  

    var dec = $('#decode'),
        enc = $('#encode');
    $.base64.utf8encode = true;
    enc.keyup(function () {
        dec.val($.base64.btoa(this.value));
    });
    dec.keyup(function () {
        enc.val($.base64.atob(this.value, true));
    });
    $('textarea').on('focus blur', function () {
        $(this).prev('label').stop().fadeToggle(200);
    });
```

the user is lively seeing the encypted text as they type their name for validation purposes, i want to add date/time or a string to be included at the encrypted text while the user type and without the users knowledge, so basically the output will be:

```
//Decrypted Text:
Name, Date/Time, Mycompanyname etc ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append the data to be added before you Base64 encode the string.  The user doesn't see it in their box and if you decode the encoded output, then it will have the additional information attached.

http://jsfiddle.net/uwxw632f/5/

```
function addMetadata(str) {
    return str + ', ' + new Date() + ', Mycompanyname, etc...';
}

var dec = $('#decode'),
    enc = $('#encode');
$.base64.utf8encode = true;
enc.keyup(function () {
    dec.val($.base64.btoa(addMetadata(this.value)));
});
dec.keyup(function () {
    enc.val($.base64.atob(this.value, true));
});
$('textarea').on('focus blur', function () {
    $(this).prev('label').stop().fadeToggle(200);
});
```

Note that *encryption*  is different from *encoding* and that it's trivial for a user to reverse base64 *encoding*.

Comment: with your added code, i manage to create link download for the user, [https://jsfiddle.net/amp4hxhr/](https://jsfiddle.net/amp4hxhr/)